# R[write to console]: Error in gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim) : 3 arguments passed to .Internal(gettext) which requires 2

Tags: python, r

I want to use R function in python, I installed rpy2 in python. when I want to load the function (from rpy2 import robjects), I face with bellow error:

R[write to console]: Error in gettext(fmt, domain = domain, trim = trim) :    3 arguments passed to .Internal(gettext) which requires 2

I would be very grateful if you know about this issue, guide me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Might be related https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/874